# Deploying Zend application in Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hi i need help on deploying zend framework based application on aws beanstalk..so far i already configure aws rds for mysql database, but deploying application in beanstalk didn't work for me, also need to know what is purpose of Application Health Check URL for and Document Root is used refer to what? Thanks [-}

Comment: OK - why didn't it work? We can't see your screen, the site or the server, so you need to give us a few clues if you want help!

Comment: its gives error on URL health check..

Comment: what is default way off running zend framework based application on beans talk...if index.php in public folder what changes should i made to Document Root ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions is to run the beanstalk with Sample application. By doing this it will create an instance EC2 and get adapt with the environment. After that try to upload your application and set the url for healthcheck as '/' and root folder as '/'.

If you still get health check failed, you had to wait for a  while till EC2 instance done with its status check.